# Error in drop_download: Conflict (HTTP 409)

Tags: r, shiny, persistent-storage

I am buiolding a Shiny up where I'd like users to download data from a Dropbox account for use in the application. The downloaded data is entered by users in previous sessions.

Whenever I try to download the data, I receive the following error message:

```
Downloading: 87 B     Warning: Error in drop_download: Conflict (HTTP 409).
156: <Anonymous>
```

I don't think it is an issue with Dropbox authentication as I can successfully upload files to the Dropbox folder, I just can't download them.

My simplest reproducible code is below. Any help with this would be much appreciated!

```
#token <- drop_auth()
#saveRDS(token, "my-token.rds")
#drop_auth(rdstoken = "my-token.rds")

token <- readRDS("my-token.rds")
outputDir<-"Ed_app_save"

f_saveData <- function(data,name1) {
  
  data <- t(data)
  fileName <- sprintf(name1, as.integer(Sys.time()), digest::digest(data))
  filePath <- file.path(tempdir(), fileName)
  write.csv(data, filePath, row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
  drop_upload(filePath, path = outputDir, dtoken = token)
  
}

f_loadData <- function(filename) {
  
  filesInfo <- subset(drop_dir(outputDir), name=filename)
  filePaths <- filesInfo$path_display
  data <- lapply(filePaths, drop_read_csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  data

  }

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  br(),
  actionButton("save_inputs", "Save inputs"),
  actionButton("load_inputs", "Load inputs"),
  br(),
  br(),
  div(uiOutput("intro_text"))
  
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
  
  
  observeEvent(input$save_inputs,{
    
    f_saveData(c(1,2,3),"name_of_file.csv")
    
  })
  
  
  downloaded_stuff<-eventReactive(input$load_inputs,{
    
    f_loadData("name_of_file.csv")
    
  })
  

  output$intro_text<-renderUI({
    
    tagList(div(
      ifelse(input$load_inputs==0,
         "Nothing loaded yet",
         downloaded_stuff())
      ))
  })
  
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue, posting in case it helps others.

The issue was with the loadData function - filePaths was returning multiple files in the folder. The following managed to resolve the issue.

```
f_loadData <- function(filename) {
  
  filesInfo <- subset(drop_dir(outputDir), name=filename)
  temp <- filesInfo$path_display
  filePaths <- temp[which(temp==paste0("/",outputDir,"/",filename))]
  data <- drop_read_csv(filePaths)
  data
 
}
```